# Java: creating several instances of object in class itself or how to restructure

Tags: java, class, object, structure

I'm a java beginner and have a question concerning how to best structure a cooking program.
I have a class called Ingredient, this class currently looks like this:

```
public class Ingredient {

    private String identifier;
    private double ingredientFactor;
    private String titleInterface;

    public Ingredient(String identifier, double ingredientFactor,String titleInterface) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.ingredientFactor = ingredientFactor;
        this.titleInterface = titleInterface;
    }
```

I want to initialize several objects (about 40) with certain values as instance variables and save them in a Map, for example

```
Map<String, Ingredient> allIngredients = new HashMap<String, Ingredient>();
allIngredients.put("Almonds (ground)", new Ingredient("Almonds (ground)", 0.7185, "Almonds (ground)");
```

Later on I want to retrieve all these objects in the form of a Map/HashMap in a different class.
I'm not sure how to proceed best, initialize all these objects in the Ingredient class itself or provide a method that initializes it or would it be better to create an super class (AllIngredients or something like that?) that has a Map with Ingredients as instance variables?

Happy for any suggestions, thanks in advance :)

Comment: you should not initialize the attributes in class, rather have multiple constructors / even methods, which initialize them. secondly, have a method which constructs a map using all the attributes and returns the map. These methods, can then be reused later in some other class,.

Comment: If there is a fixed amount of ingredients, then you could also use an enum.

Comment: Definitely a separate class. And ideally the actual data in a text file, not in Java source code.

Comment: IMHO the Map<String,Ingredient> is redundat since the information which ingredient it is is stored within ingredient. You might have a class lets say Receipt which has a field List<Ingredient> which stores all ingredients. You can get the names via an Iterator.

Comment: Since `AllIngredients` looks like container for stuff, it must not be super- (or sub-) class of `Ingredients`. For example, it can be pure wrapper of a `Map` with utility methods to put and retrieve stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not initialize all these objects in the Ingredient class itself. That would be a bad practice for oops.

Just think your class is a template from which you create copies(objects) with different values for attributes. In real world if your class represent model for a toy plane which you would use to create multiple toy planes but each bearing different name and color then think how such a system would be designed. You will have a model(class). Then a system(another class) for getting required color and name from different selection of colors and names present(like in database,files,property file ) etc.

Regarding your situation .

1. If predetermined values store the values in a text file,properties file,database,constants in class etc depending on the sensitivity of the data.
2. Create Ingredient  class with constructors
3. Create a class which will have methods to initialize Ingredient class using predetermined values,update the values if required,save the values to text file -database etc and in your case return as map .

Also check the links below

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are looking for a `static Map`.

```
public class Ingredient {

    private String identifier;
    private double ingredientFactor;
    private String titleInterface;

    public Ingredient(String identifier, double ingredientFactor, String titleInterface) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.ingredientFactor = ingredientFactor;
        this.titleInterface = titleInterface;
    }

    static Map<String, Ingredient> allIngredients = new HashMap<String, Ingredient>();

    static {
        // Build my main set.
        allIngredients.put("Almonds (ground)", new Ingredient("Almonds (ground)", 0.7185, "Almonds (ground)"));
    }
}
```